# For $0 < x < 1$, express $\sin[\sin^{-1}(x) + \cos^{-1}(x)]$, in terms of $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I need to express $\sin[\sin^{-1}(x) + \cos^{-1}(x)]$, in terms of $x$, if $0 < x < 1$.

I'm not sure how to solve this. If I knew the value of $x$, I would try and apply the identity, $\sin(A-B)=\sin(A)\cos(B)+ \cos(A)\sin(A)$, but since the answer is the real number $1$, I don't see how that would work.

For example:
$$\sin[\sin^{-1}(x) + \cos^{-1}(x)]$$
$$\sin[\sin^{-1}(x)] \cdot \cos[\cos^{-1}(x)] + \cos[\sin^{-1}(x)] \cdot \sin[\cos^{-1}(x)]$$
$$x \cdot x + \cos[\sin^{-1}(x)] \cdot \sin[\cos^{-1}(x)]$$
$$x^2 + \cos[\sin^{-1}(x)] \cdot \sin[\cos^{-1}(x)]$$

That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-prove-arcsin-x-arccos-x-pi-2

Comment: Hint: $\arcsin x+ \arccos x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the fact $$\cos(u)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2 u}\\\sin(u)=\sqrt{1-\cos^2 u}$$we have $$\cos [\sin^{-1}x]\cdot \sin [\cos^{-1}x]=\sqrt{1-\sin^2 (\sin^{-1}x)}\cdot \sqrt{1-\cos^2 (\cos^{-1}x)}=1-x^2$$therefore $$\large  \sin[\sin^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}x]=1$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how that helps.

Comment: Then you can substitute $u=\sin^{-1}x$ and $u=\cos^{-1}x$ in the first and second equations respectively

Comment: So, instead of $\sin[\sin^{-1}(x) + \cos^{-1}(x)]$, I'll have $\sin[u + u]$?

Comment: I clarified my answer a bit more. Hope it help now!

Comment: So, why does $\sqrt{1-\sin^2 (\sin^{-1}x)}\cdot \sqrt{1-\cos^2 (\cos^{-1}x)} = 1 - x^2$ ?

Comment: Because $$\sin^2 (\sin^{-1}x)=(\sin(\sin^{-1}x))^2=x^2$$whenever $0\le x\le 1$ also similarly for $\cos^2 (\cos^{-1}x)$

Comment: But, doesn't that just mean, $\sqrt{1-\sin^2 (\sin^{-1}x)}\cdot \sqrt{1-\cos^2 (\cos^{-1}x)} = \sqrt{x^2} \cdot \sqrt{x^2} = x^2$ ? Why do you get $1 - x^2$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86158/discussion-between-mostafa-ayaz-and-luminousnutria).

Answer (score 1):

Write $\cos(\sin^{-1} x)$ as $\sin(\frac\pi2 - \sin^{-1}x)$ and expand using the identity.

Similarly, solve the other term by writing $\sin(\cos^{-1} x)$ as $\cos(\frac\pi2 - \cos^{-1} x)$ and expanding it using an identity.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use

$$\arcsin x = y_1 \implies \sin y_1 = x$$

$$\arccos x = y_2 \implies \cos y_2 = x$$

and

$$\cos \theta = \sin \bigg(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\bigg)$$

to get

$$\implies y_2 = \frac{\pi}{2}-y_1$$

So what does $y_1+y_2$ become?

Comment: You've got to be careful here $\sin y_1=\cos y_2$ doesn't necessarily imply that $y_2=\frac{\pi}{2}-y_1$. For example, $\sin (\frac{\pi}{2})=\cos (2\pi)$.

Comment: But $2\pi  = 0 $ (in radians), so you get $\sin \frac{\pi}{2} = \cos 0$.

Comment: what do you mean by $2\pi=0$? !!!

Comment: (Awful wording, I edited the comment.) I meant $0$ radians and $2\pi$ radians are the same.

Comment: No they are not. $0$ radian is $0^{\circ}$ and $2\pi$ radian is $360^{\circ}$.

Comment: $360°$ is one full revolution and lands back on $0°$ though.

Comment: Just because function value is the same at two inputs, doesn't mean the inputs are same.